# how to start display server?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

I was trying to install nvidia driver from the official nvidia.com sit on a server
I was fowlling the installation and in order to complete the installation I should have done the below command where I Disable Nouveau Nvidia driver using the follow:

```
$ sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
$ sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
```

then I suppose to Stop Desktop Manager using the following:

```
sudo telinit 3
```

the installation completed successfully...but now when I trying to login through remote desktop using a Xrog session no thing display and that was expected...please how I can start the desktop manager again in order to let the device display things again or should I do another thing...thanks in advanse. inform for more details if needed.

Comment: At first you do not tell what happens when trying to launch the xorg-server. Anyway : the Xorg.log (usually in /var/log) should tell you.

Comment: dear I am trying to log in via remot desktop from a windows device after entering the credential into Xrog successfuly but tnothing display on the screen I mean the system not displaying any thing

Comment: After disabling Nouveau, you'd need to configure the Xorg display server to use the `nvidia` driver instead, either manually or by running `nvidia-xconfig` - did you do that? The Windows remote desktop protocol (RDP) is not at all the same thing as the X11; they are not compatible at all. It is possible to have a RDP server process installed on Linux, but it is not the default - and the RDP session will be entirely separate from the local GUI session anyway.

Comment: Dear thank you for the enlightenment, no I have not configure   nvidia, do you have any idea how I could do that?